# How to filter Mongodb $lookup results to get only the matched nested objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `customers` collection such as;

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5de8c07dc035532b489b2e23"),
  "name" : "sam",
  "orders" : [{"ordername" : "cola"},{"ordername" : "cheesecake"}]
}
```

And `waiters` collection such as;

```
{   
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de8bc24c035532b489b2e20"),
    "waiter" : "jack",
    "products" : [{"name" : "cola", "price" : "4"}, 
                  {"name" : "water", "price" : "2"}, 
                  {"name" : "coffee", "price" : "8" }]
}
{   
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de8bdc7c035532b489b2e21"),
    "waiter" : "susan",
    "products" : [{"name" : "cheesecake", "price" : "12" }, 
                  {"name" : "apple pie", "price" : "14" }]
}
```

I want to join the objects from `waiters` collection into the `customers` collection by matching "products.name" and "orders.ordername". But, the result includes the whole document from the `waiters` collection, however, I want only the matched objects inside the document. Here is what I want;

```
ordered:[ 
  {"name" : "cola", "price" : "4"},
  {"name" : "cheesecake", "price" : "12" },
]
```

I tried `$lookup` with and without pipeline, and filter but could not get this result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, we just have to "massage" the data a bit due to its structure like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "orderNames":
                {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$orders",
                        initialValue: [],
                        in: {$concatArrays: [["$$this.ordername"], "$$value"]}
                    }
                }
        }
    },
    {
      $lookup:
          {
            from: "waiters",
            let: {orders: "$orderNames"},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $unwind: "$products"
                },
                {
                    $match:
                        {
                            $expr:{$in: ["$products.name", "$$orders"]},
                        }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$products.name",
                        price: {$first: "$products.price"}
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        price: 1,
                        name: "$_id"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "ordered"
        }
    }
])
```

- It feels like you could benefit from a new collection of mapping items to prices. Could potentially save you a lot of time.

Comment: What is that instock, order_qty in the answer? There are not such fields in the sample documents.

Comment: Mb I forgot to delete that

Comment: Your updated query does not give the result he wanted, did you try your query?

Comment: ordered is in the right format. i'm not sure what your talking about.

Comment: Check your query here https://mongoplayground.net/p/crgwbj6kQRq

Comment: you're right i copied the wrong lookup stage. updated.

Comment: Here is your updated query, still not works as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LIhYP4E_Xnm

Comment: change the collection name in the lookup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203677/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-tom-slabbaert).

Comment: Works fine. Thanks